# Bootstrap button drop downs not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I can't get Bootstrap v3 button drop downs to work in my Angular 4 app with `ngx-bootstrap`.

The Bootstrap v3 documentation sample does not work in my component. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My module imports these modules from `ngx-bootstrap`...

```
import {AccordionModule, BsDropdownModule, CollapseModule, ModalModule, ProgressbarModule, TooltipModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Bootstrap Modules
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
]
})
```

Comment: Try these docs: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out... I wasn't looking at the drop down documentation for `ngx-bootstrap` and was only looking through the button documentation.

Here's the link with instructions for button drop downs. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns